# Generating pdf file from express-handlebars render with html-pdf library, css files not working

Tags: handlebars.js, pdf-generation, express-handlebars, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I'm trying to generating a pdf file which is generated from express-handlebars rendering. However, some css files don't seem to be working.

Bootstrap are still working okays, but the custom css (i'm using a theme) is not working. I have tried phantomjs config (--web-security=false,...), switching css folder directory from local to the server. But none of them seems to be working. Images are working fine.

generating html and creating pdf files

```
var config = {
        format: "A4",
        orientation: "landscape",
        base: "http://127.0.0.1:3002/uploads/theme/",
        timeout: 100000, 
        phantomArgs: ["--web-security=false","--local-to-remote-url-access=true"]
    }

    var html = await hbs.render('./views/pdf.handlebars', data)
    await fs.writeFile("pdf.html", html, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    })
    var fileName = uuid.v4()
    await pdf.create(html, config).toFile(`./downloads/${fileName}.pdf`, function (err, res) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        response.send({ success: true, data: { downloadURL: fileName } })
```

including css files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.min.css">
```

server receiving calls from css files:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPjpw.png)

Expecting results:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f1F3.png)

Actual result:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFCUo.png)

As you can see, bootstrap and font-awesome are working fine, but the "style.css" is not working. Anyone have any idea about this problems? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your server code is reading only HTML files and not css files , so css is actually being not used,  **use inline css**.
I am also looking for methods to write separate HTML and CSS and merge to form pdf.

Comment: what i did is i wrote <style> my css </style>

then i read both HTML and css and merge the files.
`let tempHTML = fs.readFileSync(index.html);

    let tempCss = fs.readFileSync(index.css')

    dataSrc = tempCss.toString() +   tempHTML.toString()

    let template = Handlebars.compile(dataSrc);

    let resultTemp = template(data);`

Comment: exactly. copy bootstrap css source and place it inside <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"> </style> under head and viola!